# Getting Syntax error for Regex while trying to put a MaskEpression for my TextEdit

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textEdit in which I want to put a mask with a Regex expression that allows user to text only Uppercase Extended ASCII characters.

This is the regex : **^[^\P{Lu}\P{Latin}]{0,10}$**

And I am trying to put it in code like this:

```
        textEdit.Properties.MaskSettings.Configure<MaskSettings.RegExp>(settings =>
        {
           settings.MaskExpression = "^[^\\P{Lu}\\P{Latin}]{0,10}$";
        });
```

I am getting syntax errors. How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance, any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tried your pattern using this tester:
http://regexstorm.net/tester

It says that C# Regex doesn't know property named Latin.

When I change Latin to IsBasicLatin, it works with this pattern:

**^[^\P{Lu}\P{IsBasicLatin}]{0,10}$**

Comment: I still have Syntax error. ^[^\P{Lu}\P{IsBasicLatin}]{0,10}$ with this one it can't compile cause Unrecognized escape sequence, so I put \\ instead of \, and this one : ^[^\\P{Lu}\\P{IsBasicLatin}]{0,10}$ has Syntax error at runtime